# I always get the statut code 401 when I check discord token

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

The Discord API always return {"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0} but the token is valid.

I'm trying to find out if the Discord token is valid. I tried this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

const BaseURL = 'https://discord.com/api/v9';
const headers = {
  Authorization: `Bot ${args[1]}}`
}

xhr.open('GET', `${BaseURL}/users/@me`, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', headers.Authorization);
xhr.send()
xhr.onreadystatechange = async function() { 
  console.log(xhr)
  var status_code = xhr.status
}
```

Comment: What is `args[]`?

Comment: It's the token. It is valid.

Comment: Does the additional `}` in `Bot ${args[1]}}` also appear in your code, or is this just a typo here ...?

Comment: It's a typo here

Comment: Then either `args[1]` is not what you think it is, or your token is not valid for a `Bot` ...

Comment: The problem is with my web host.